# AutoCompleteTextView + Speech to Text on Keyboard

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In Android AutoCompleteTextView, I have set the threshold value to 3, and so the dropdown menu would show after I type three letters. But, if I use the speech to text on the virtual keyboard, when the word appears, it is highlighted and the dropdown menu does not show.
I have tried using addTextChangedListener to force a showDropDown() in a TextWatcher, but I believe this makes the dropdown menu show before the text highlight, and so it would hide it immediately after.
Has someone dealt with this issue before?

Thanks.